# How should I understand usage of %eax register in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have hard time understanding assembly code. Specially I am confused with using register.
Below code is recursive function which is counting numbers of '1' in binary number !!

```
/*recursive popcount*/
long pcount_r(unsigned long x) {
if (x == 0)
return 0;
else
return (x & 1)
+ pcount_r(x >> 1);
}
```

The first code is written by c and second code is assembly code.

```
pcount_r:
movl $0, %eax
testq %rdi, %rdi
je .L6
pushq %rbx
movq %rdi, %rbx
andl $1, %ebx
shrq %rdi # (by 1)
call pcount_r
addq %rbx, %rax
popq %rbx
.L6:
rep; ret
```

At the second line of assembly code register eax is used. So I have question about eax !

1. Is register %eax is part of %rax?
2. What is the meaning of the second line in assembly code? (movl $0, %eax)
3. Can I change %eax to %rax at the second line of assembly code?

I try to find answer but most of the explanation was hard to understand. Help me please !!

Comment: If you compile with full optimization, GCC will hopefully do a better job, turning it into a loop.  https://godbolt.org/z/TYb3nExPG.  Unfortunately neither GCC nor clang spot the pattern and optimize it into a `popcnt` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is register %eax is part of %rax?

yes -- it is the lower 32 bits of the 64-bit %rax

> What is the meaning of the second line in assembly code? (movl $0, %eax)

It loads a 0 into those lower 32 bits of %rax and then sets the upper 32 bits to 0 (all instructions with a 32-bit destination set the upper 32 bits of the 64-bit register to 0)

> Can I change %eax to %rax at the second line of assembly code?

Yes, and it would likely generate exactly the same instruction.  It might generate an instruction with a REX prefix which does the same thing (so a 1-byte larger instruction).  You could also use `xor %eax, %eax` or `xor %rax, %rax` for the same effect.